# Creating Tutorial upon first login

Tags: python, django, signals, python-social-auth, receiver

I am currently using python social auth to login users into my Django app and show a tutorial upon first user creation. I've tried this so far but request does not work in pre_save signals. Is there another way to do this?

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=User)
def show_tutorial(sender, instance=None, **kwargs):
    # For first time creation of user display tutorial
    if instance._state.adding:
        print ('USER CREATED')
        request.session['first_login'] = True
```

EDIT: I tried the following code in my views but once logging in, the print statement never logged in the terminal.

```
def after_user_created(request, user, **kwargs):
    user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    if created:
         request.session['first_login'] = True
         print('FIRST LOGIN')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it. You should not do it even if you could do it. Let's do the operation on "request" as much as possible on "view". like this.

```
def create_view(request):
    user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(id=xxx)
    if created:
         request.session['first_login'] = True
```

**UPDATE**

Add a solution that assumes using "[social-app-django](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django/tree/master/social_django)".

① set settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_NEW_USER_REDIRECT_URL

```
NEW_USER_REDIRECT_URL=/new/user/view
```

http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/settings.html?highlight=NEW_USER_REDIRECT_URL#urls-options

② Update session with new user view。

```
def new_user_view(request):
    request.session['first_login'] = True
```

Comment: Check the edits above. I tried this, but for some reason the request was not going through as the print statement never showed up in the terminal.

Comment: @Viji123 Is this the library you are using?  https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core

Comment: @Viji123 Update my answer. Please try again.